# input.value is returning undefined

Tags: jquery, html

Input:

```
<input type="radio" name="options" id="onetime" autocomplete="off" value="90" class='planSelect'> One-Time 6 Months
```

jQuery:

```
$('.planSelect').value;
```

This is returning "90undefined" and I have no idea why?

Comment: `.val()`, not value.  value is a dom property.  jQuery uses the val() method.

Comment: `console.log($('.planSelect').length)` and see what it prints

Answer (score 2):

> $('.planSelect') returns a jQuery selector, use .val to access its value

Use $('.planSelect').val(); instead.

```js
let index = 0;
let randomColors = ["red","green","blue"];

function run(){
     $("#result").text($('.planSelect').val()).css("color",randomColors[index++%3]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="options" id="onetime" autocomplete="off" value="90" class='planSelect'> One-Time 6 Months
<div> Result: <span id="result"></span></div>
<button onclick="run()">Rerun</button>
```

Comment: .val() is returning the same thing

Comment: For some reason this is still not working for me. Maybe it's because there are multiple inputs with that class? I was using $('.planSelect')[1].val()

Comment: @David try to avoid directly using index for your result to make your selector more robust, such as $('.planSelect:last') in case your html changes or even an id for your target would be better.